# handling invalid parameter exception in C++

Tags: c++, linux, porting

I have the following code written in CLI C++:

```
static void BadTraceHandler(const wchar_t* expression,
    const wchar_t* function, 
    const wchar_t* file, 
    unsigned int line, 
    uintptr_t pReserved)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(expression);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(function);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(file);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(line);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pReserved);

    sBadTrace = 1;
}

void func ()
{
    newHandler = BadTraceHandler;
    oldHandler = _set_invalid_parameter_handler(newHandler);

    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, 0);
    sBadTrace = 0;

    __try
    {
        vsnprintf_s((char*)pDisplayStr, MAX_TRACE_LEN, _TRUNCATE, (char*)pTempFormat, (va_list)pList);
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        sBadTrace = 1;
    }   

    _set_invalid_parameter_handler(oldHandler);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW);
}
```

The goal of this code is to basically set sBadTrace to 1 in case the function vsnprintf_s receives a bad parameter and for that purpose two mechanisems are used - the __try, __except(1) and the _set_invalid_parameter_handler. None of those is supported in standard C++ (they are Microsoft specific).

I am trying to make this code compatible for Linux so i rewire it in STL C++. 
To achieve this I changed __try, __except(1) to try, catch(...), which i hope will work the same in case of an invalid parameter (although i couldn't fin information about the kind of exceptions vsnprintf_s throws). Is it an equivalent code?

As to _set_invalid_parameter_handler - i am not sure how to replicate this mechanism in Linux. I know all about using signals but i couldn't find a signal that's triggered when an invalid parameter is passed to a function.

Comment: There are no invalid parameters in C++. There is only undefined behavior.

Comment: This is Microsoft doing some low-level implementation specific stuff. It is unlikely you will be able to duplicate it elsewhere without writing a bunch of code. `vsnprintf_s` only marginally exists in standard C++ so be warned. It might not be implemented. You need to implement and install a [Constraint Handler](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s) that performs the behaviours, throws the exceptions, you want. You will also probably have to define the exceptions.

Comment: I've never done this, so I can't give an authoritative answer without doing a lot of work I don't have time for at the moment. Once you get this all figured out and have a working solution, this will make a brilliant self-answered question.

Comment: But one last point, you wouldn't be having any of these issues if you wrote standard-compliant C++ and used iostreams. This is still possible to do in CLI and would remove virtually all of your portability concerns.

Comment: @user4581301 what do you mean by using iostreams? How do i replace vsnprintf_s functionality by iostreams? Also - this code somehow detects incorrect parameters and uses that info to set a flag - how do i overcome the need of doing that simply by using iostreams? Thanks

Comment: With iostreams the compiler figures out from the provided datatypes 
 how to print and the program won't compile if it can't figure it out. if you use a std::stringstream, the receptacle will resize itself so you never need worry about buffer overflow. About the only runtime error that leaves is a catchable out of memory exception if the stream cannot resize. That said, I have no clue where `pTempFormat` and `pList` came from, so your mileage may vary on this one.